# how to user CURL to send our request to www.google-analytics.com/collect

Tags: curl, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have been going though the documentation for the  [Universal analytics measurement protocol](https://developers.google.cn/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference)

I have gotten theurl and parameter, now I have a question is that how I can make a HTTP request with CURL, here is my request:

```
curl https://www.google-analytics.com/collect -d v=1&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=5555&t=pageview&dp=%2FpageA
```

Error:

> Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell
> Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output
> Warning: " to save to a file.

Can you tell me what is wrong in my request?

Answer (score 0):

I would test it with the debug endpoint first.

```
curl 'https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=5555&t=pageview&dp=%2FpageA'
```

The response says its all good.

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026tid=UA-123456-1\u0026cid=5555\u0026t=pageview\u0026dp=%2FpageA"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

Followed by sending the actual hit.

```
curl 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=5555&t=pageview&dp=%2FpageA'
```